# Codeigniter Email library gives error when sending html mail

Tags: php, codeigniter, html-email

Hi i am using codeigniter email library to send mail. It works fine in default config (mailtype=text). But when i change mailtype to 'html' it sends a blank email. Below is my code.

```
public function sendmail($mail){
    $config = Array( 
        'useragent' => 'SPTechbook.com', 
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'crlf'     => '\r\n',
        'newline'  => '\r\n',
        'charset' => 'iso-8859-1'
         );     
    $this->load->library('email',$config);


    $this->email->from('donot-reply@sptechbook.com', 'SPTechbook');

    $this->email->to($mail); 

    $this->email->subject('Email Verification');
    $message=$this->load->view('templates/email/email.php',TRUE);
    $this->email->message($message);

    $this->email->send();

    echo $this->email->print_debugger();

}
```

Below is the output of print_debugger()

```
Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

User-Agent: SPTechbook.com
Date: Sun, 3 Aug 2014 06:21:14 +0000
From: "SPTechbook" <donot-reply@sptechbook.com>
Return-Path: <donot-reply@sptechbook.com>
Reply-To: "donot-reply@sptechbook.com" <donot-reply@sptechbook.com>
X-Sender: donot-reply@sptechbook.com
X-Mailer: SPTechbook.com
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <53ddd4daa9a57@sptechbook.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_53ddd4daa9aa1"


=?iso-8859-1?Q?Email_Verification?=
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ALT_53ddd4daa9aa1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit




--B_ALT_53ddd4daa9aa1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable



--B_ALT_53ddd4daa9aa1--
```

also i have tried with crlf='\n' and newline='\n' but no success, I get a blank email. Also tried with charset UTF-8 but no success. The email template is not blank either. It is a complete webpage with a proper body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is your data?

```
$message=$this->load->view('templates/email/email.php', $your_data, TRUE);
```

See last paragraph: [Returning views as data](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html).

Comment: So in your code `TRUE` is for `$data`, not for `return` of view.